# Positioning similar type objects on form programmatically in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, for-loop, logic

I have a from which contains some PictureBoxes. They can be from one to many.
I create them at run-time depending on the existence of specific folders.

I create them and place them the one next to each other. This means that with a scrollable form I can view all of them easy.

My question is this: How do I position them in "rows"? For a specific form size, there can be 5 labels next to each other and infinite rows of them

How do I achieve this?
My (working) code:

```
Public allSeries As IEnumerable(Of String) = System.IO.Directory.EnumerateDirectories(root)

For i As Integer = 1 To allSeries.Count

        Dim pb As New Windows.Forms.PictureBox With {
            .Name = "pb" & i.ToString,
            .Size = New Drawing.Size(500, 500),
            .Location = New Point(5, 5),
            .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
            .SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom,
            .Image = Image.FromFile(allSeries(i - 1).ToString + "\sImage.jpg"),
            .Tag = traveldestination, 'Store Directory path
            .Cursor = Cursors.Hand}
        Me.Controls.Add(pb)

For i As Integer = 2 To allSeries.Count
        With Me
            .Controls.Item("pb" + i.ToString).Left = .Controls.Item("pb" + (i - 1).ToString).Left + 520
        End With
    Next
```

My (bad) and (not workng) code:

```
Dim pbsOnForm As Integer = 13 'total PictureBoxes on Form /for this instance
    Dim pbsOnRow As Integer = 5 'PictureBoxes that "fit" in a row /for this intance)
    
    For i As Integer = 1 To pbsOnForm
        If i <= pbsOnRow Then
            Me.Controls.Item("pb" + i.ToString).Top = Me.Controls.Item("pb" + i.ToString).Top
        End If
        If i > pbsOnRow And i <= 10 Then
            Me.Controls.Item("pb" + i.ToString).Top = Me.Controls.Item("pb" + (i - pbsOnRow).ToString).Top
        End If
```

Works, but when the PcrureBoxes will be more than 10, I do not know......

Comment: Use a TableLayoutPanel to layout your Controls. -- An *infinite rows of them* expectation is bound to cause grief.

Answer (score 0):

While using the TableLayoutPanel would fulfill most cases for this and is probably the best way to achieve this, here is some code to align the PictureBox's in row / column.

First we want to setup a method to handle the positioning. We need some variables scoped to the Form.

```
Dim counter As Integer = 0
Dim xPos As Integer = 5
Dim yPos As Integer = 5
```

Now we use these variables in a method that sets the location.

```
Private Sub PositionPictureBox(pb As PictureBox, Optional imgPerRow As Integer = 5)
    pb.Location = New Point(xPos, yPos)
    counter += 1
    If counter = imgPerRow Then
        counter = 0
        xPos = 5
        yPos = pb.Location.Y + pb.Height + 5
    Else
        xPos = pb.Location.X + pb.Width + 5
    End If
End Sub
```

Finally we call the method when the PictureBox is instantiated.

```
    For i As Integer = 1 To allSeries.Count
        Dim pb As New Windows.Forms.PictureBox
        With pb
            .Name = "pb" & i.ToString()
            .Size = New Drawing.Size(50, 50)
            .Location = New Point(5, 5)
            .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
            .SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
            .Image = Image.FromFile("...")
            .Tag = allSeries(i)
            .Cursor = Cursors.Hand
        End With
        PositionPictureBox(pb)
        Me.Controls.Add(pb)
    Next
```